Code Pipeline does not create action for a new stack
My app is designed in a cross-account fashion when I have 3 accounts:

root (having domains and SES stack)
dev (having application-required stacks like S3, DynamoDb or ApiGateway)
prod (-||-)

CI/CD is handled using Code Build and changes to the environment are done via CodePipeline:
export class AppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public constructor(scope: Construct, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, AppStack.name, props);

    const rootStage = new RootStage(this, {
      env: { account: AWS_ACCOUNTS.root, region: MAIN_REGION }
    });

    const devStage = new AppStage(this, `${AppStage.name}Dev`, {
      subdomain: SUB_DOMAINS.dev,
      env: { account: AWS_ACCOUNTS.dev, region: MAIN_REGION }
    });

    const prodStage = new AppStage(this, `${AppStage.name}Prod`, {
      subdomain: SUB_DOMAINS.prod,
      env: { account: AWS_ACCOUNTS.prod, region: MAIN_REGION }
    });

    // Dev Deployment
    const devPipeline = getDevPipelineStack(this);
    devPipeline.addStage(rootStage);
    devPipeline.addStage(devStage);

    // Prod Deployment
    const prodPipeline = getProdPipelineStack(this);
    prodPipeline.addStage(rootStage);
    prodPipeline.addStage(prodStage);
  }
}

Also what is worth sharing is devPipeline:
export function getDevPipelineStack(scope: Construct): pipelines.CodePipeline {
  const cdkSourceInput = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub(
    `${GITHUB_ORG}/${GITHUB_REPO}`,
    DEV_BRANCH,
    { authentication: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(GITHUB_TOKEN_NAME) }
  );

  return new pipelines.CodePipeline(scope, 'DeployDevPipeline', {
    crossAccountKeys: true,
    pipelineName: 'DeployDevPipeline',
    publishAssetsInParallel: false,
    synth: new pipelines.ShellStep('Synth', {
      input: cdkSourceInput,
      installCommands: ['npm i -g aws-cdk esbuild'],
      commands: ['cd cdk', 'npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth --verbose --trace -e'],
      primaryOutputDirectory: 'cdk/cdk.out'
    })
  });
}

I recently extended AppStage by a new stack called "SupportApi" which contains LambdaRestApiGateway resource. The problem is that this particular stack was not recognized by CodeBuild and it did not create a new action in the AppStage. The workaround is to get back to manual cdk deploy which however totally kills the idea of using CodeBuild.
Other findings

code pipeline runs without errors
cdk_synth outputs does not contain a newly created stack in the cloudformation templates (while running cdk synth locally produces it)
the changes were pushed and the pipeline triggering commit contains the new stack

Have you ever dealt with such a problem or can you think of what's worth the inspection in such a situation? Right now I am clueless.

Did you push the code change to your repo? :D If local synth was able to synthesise the change but not your pipeline which is pulling from repo, then your change must be missing in the repo?

Yes, I did. Let me add it to the description

Did you try to trigger the pipeline manually from the console? If not can your try it?

I tried to trigger it manually via "release change" but nothing has changed, unfortunately.

The problem disappeared when "-e" flag from cdk synth command got removed.
export function getDevPipelineStack(scope: Construct): pipelines.CodePipeline {
  const cdkSourceInput = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub(
    `${GITHUB_ORG}/${GITHUB_REPO}`,
    DEV_BRANCH,
    { authentication: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(GITHUB_TOKEN_NAME) }
  );

  return new pipelines.CodePipeline(scope, 'DeployDevPipeline', {
    crossAccountKeys: true,
    pipelineName: 'DeployDevPipeline',
    publishAssetsInParallel: false,
    synth: new pipelines.ShellStep('Synth', {
      input: cdkSourceInput,
      installCommands: ['npm i -g aws-cdk esbuild'],
      commands: ['cd cdk', 'npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth --verbose --trace -e'], // OUCH
      primaryOutputDirectory: 'cdk/cdk.out'
    })
  });
}


$ cdk synth help
...
  -e, --exclusively        Only synthesize requested stacks, don't include
                           dependencies

